# Multi-dimensional dataframe or multiple 2D dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

A colleague wrote some code to create a price lookup table for products where the prices change throughout the year. He also stores other information like the name of the season, when it starts, ends, etc. His code takes nine minutes to run on a beefy machine.

His approach is the traditional SQL-loop-over-records algorithms. I wanted to see if I could do better using matrices, so I wrote a price table (of only prices) using Pandas.  My code runs in 21 seconds on a Macbook Air. Cool.

My next step is to add in other attributes like name of the season, when it starts, ends, etc. It's my understanding that I shouldn't store objects in my dataframes because that will reduce speed, is Bad Practice, etc.

I think I have two options: 1. for each new piece of data add another dimension so the shape of my dataframe would go from (product X days) to (product X days X season_name X season_start X season_end) or 2. I would just create a new dataframe for each attribute and jump back and forth between them as necessary.

My goal is to use pandas for very quick lookups and calculations of data.

Or is there a better more pandas-ish way to do this?

Comment: As you said, don't store dataframes inside dataframes. `pandas` does not allow a third axis, as far as I know. A dataframe is a 2D table. For what you want to do, I think is better option 2. Maybe you can do it with a single big dataframe with a multiindex, too. Sadly, if you don't show us a sample of the data, we cannot give a better advice, the question as it is is too vague to give a proper answer. And I'm afraid that even if you show us the data and ask just for the better way to achieve a vague result, it will be primarly opinion based.

Comment: MultiIndex is the way to go.